# A more elegant way to parse

Tags: c, parsing, file-io, system-calls

I'm kind of new to C.
I need to write a small function that opens a configuration file that has 3 lines, each line contains a path to files/directories that I need to extract.

I wrote this program and it seem to work:

```
void readCMDFile(char* cmdFile,char directoryPath[INPUT_SIZE], char inputFilePath[INPUT_SIZE],char outputFilePath [INPUT_SIZE]) {
  //open files
  int file = open(cmdFile, O_RDONLY);
  if (file < 0) {
    handleFailure();
  }
  char buffer[BUFF_SIZE];
  int status;
  int count;
  while((count=read(file,buffer,sizeof(buffer)))>0)
  {
    int updateParam = UPDATE1;
    int i,j;
    i=0;
    j=0;
    for (;i<count;i++) {
      if (buffer[i]!='\n'&&buffer[i]!=SPACE&&buffer[i]!='\0') {
        switch (updateParam){
          case UPDATE1:
            directoryPath[j] = buffer[i];
            break;
          case UPDATE2:
            inputFilePath[j] = buffer[i];
            break;
          case UPDATE3:
            outputFilePath[j] = buffer[i];
            break;
        }
        j++;

      } else{
        switch (updateParam){
          case UPDATE1:
            updateParam = UPDATE2;
            j=0;
            break;
          case UPDATE2:
            updateParam = UPDATE3;
            j=0;
            break;

        }

      }
    }
  }
  if (count < 0) {
    handleFailure();
  }

}
```

but it is incredibly unintuitive and pretty ugly, so I thought there must be a more elegant way to do it. are there any suggestions?
Thanks!

Update: a config file content will look like that:

```
/home/bla/dirname
/home/bla/bla/file1.txt
/home/bla/bla/file2.txt
```

Comment: Why not use standard I/O (`FILE *`) instead of Unix I/O (file descriptors).  Then you have functions that will read lines of input — unlike the file descriptor functions.  Read lines; copy the relevant sections of the lines read into the output parameters.  Don't forget to drop the newlines.  Use `strcpy()` or relatives, not character-by-character operations as shown in the question.

Comment: If you post the the contents of *"a configuration file that has 3 lines"*, you can get much more substantive answer as to how you parse them. If you really have 3-lines, then a simple loop that loops over each line and then passes the line to `sscanf` for parsing would seem to be a much more straightforward way.

Comment: I'm updating the post...

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't one about parsing the contents of the file, it is simply one about reading the lines of the file into adequate storage within a function in a manner that the object containing the stored lines can be return to the calling function. This is fairly standard, but you have a number of ways to approach it.

The biggest consideration is not knowing the length of the lines to be read. You say there are currently 3-lines to be read, but there isn't any need to know beforehand how many lines there are (by knowing -- you can avoid `realloc`, but that is about the only savings)

You want to create as robust and flexible method you can for reading the lines and storing them in a way that allocates just enough memory to hold what is read. A good approach is to declare a fixed-size temporary buffer to hold each line read from the file with `fgets` and then to call `strlen` on the buffer to determine the number of characters required (as well as trimming the trailing newline included by `fgets`) Since you are reading path information the predefined macro `PATH_MAX` can be used to adequately size your temporary buffer to insure it can hold the maximum size path usable by the system. You could also use POSIX `geline` instead of `fgets`, but we will stick to the C-standard library for now.

The basic type that will allow you to allocate storage for multiple lines in your function and return a single pointer you can use in the calling function is `char **` (*a pointer to pointer to char* -- or loosely an *dynamic array of pointers*). The scheme is simple, you allocate for some initial number of pointers (3 in your case) and then loop over the file, reading a line at a time, getting the length of the line, and then allocating `length + 1` characters of storage to hold the line. For example, if you allocate 3 pointers with:

```
#define NPATHS 3
...
char **readcmdfile (FILE *fp, size_t *n)
{
    ...
    char buf[PATH_MAX] = "";    /* temp buffer to hold line */
    char **paths = NULL;        /* pointer to pointer to char to return */
    size_t idx = 0;             /* index counter (avoids dereferencing) */
    ...
    paths = calloc (NPATHS, sizeof *paths); /* allocate NPATHS pointers */
    if (!paths) {                   /* validate allocation/handle error */
        perror ("calloc-paths");
        return NULL;
    }
    ...
    while (idx < NPATHS && fgets (buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
        size_t len = strlen (buf);          /* get length of string in buf */
        ...
        paths[idx] = malloc (len + 1);      /* allocate storage for line */
        if (!paths[idx]) {                  /* validate allocation */
            perror ("malloc-paths[idx]");   /* handle error */
            return NULL;
        }
        strcpy (paths[idx++], buf);     /* copy buffer to paths[idx] */
        ...
    return paths;   /* return paths */
}
```

(**note:** you can eliminate the limit of `idx < NPATHS`, if you include the check before allocating for each string and `realloc` more pointers, as required)

The remainder is just the handling of opening the file and passing the open file-stream to your function. A basic approach is to either provide the filename on the command line and then opening the filename provided with `fopen` (or read from `stdin` by default if no filename is given). As with every step in your program, you need to **validate the return** and **handle any error** to avoid processing garbage (and invoking *Undefined Behavior*)

A simple example would be:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char **paths;       /* pointer to pointer to char for paths */
    size_t i, n = 0;    /* counter and n - number of paths read */
    /* open file given by 1st argument (or read stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("fopen-failed");
        return 1;
    }

    paths = readcmdfile (fp, &n);   /* call function to read file */
                                    /* passing open file pointer */
    if (!paths) {   /* validate return from function */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: readcmdfile failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {   /* output lines read from file */
        printf ("path[%lu]: %s\n", i + 1, paths[i]);
        free (paths[i]);        /* free memory holding line */
    }
    free (paths);   /* free pointers */

    return 0;
}
```

Putting all the pieces together, adding the code the trim the `'\n'` read and included in `buf` by `fgets`, and adding an additional test to make sure the line you read actually fit in `buf`, you could do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h> /* for PATH_MAX */

#define NPATHS 3

/* read lines from file, return pointer to pointer to char on success
 * otherwise return NULL. 'n' will contain number of paths read from file.
 */
char **readcmdfile (FILE *fp, size_t *n)
{
    char buf[PATH_MAX] = "";    /* temp buffer to hold line */
    char **paths = NULL;        /* pointer to pointer to char to return */
    size_t idx = 0;             /* index counter (avoids dereferencing) */
    *n = 0;                     /* zero the pointer passed as 'n' */

    paths = calloc (NPATHS, sizeof *paths); /* allocate NPATHS pointers */
    if (!paths) {                   /* validate allocation/handle error */
        perror ("calloc-paths");
        return NULL;
    }

    /* read while index < NPATHS & good read into buf
     * (note: instead of limiting to NPATHS - you can simply realloc paths
     *  when idx == NPATHS -- but that is for later)
     */
    while (idx < NPATHS && fgets (buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
        size_t len = strlen (buf);          /* get length of string in buf */
        if (len && buf[len - 1] == '\n')    /* validate last char is '\n' */
            buf[--len] = 0;                 /* overwrite '\n' with '\0' */
        else if (len == PATH_MAX - 1) { /* check buffer full - line to long */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: path '%lu' exceeds PATH_MAX.\n", idx);
            return NULL;
        }
        paths[idx] = malloc (len + 1);      /* allocate storage for line */
        if (!paths[idx]) {                  /* validate allocation */
            perror ("malloc-paths[idx]");   /* handle error */
            return NULL;
        }
        strcpy (paths[idx++], buf);     /* copy buffer to paths[idx] */
    }
    *n = idx;       /* update 'n' to contain index - no. of lines read */

    return paths;   /* return paths */
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char **paths;       /* pointer to pointer to char for paths */
    size_t i, n = 0;    /* counter and n - number of paths read */
    /* open file given by 1st argument (or read stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("fopen-failed");
        return 1;
    }

    paths = readcmdfile (fp, &n);   /* call function to read file */
                                    /* passing open file pointer */
    if (!paths) {   /* validate return from function */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: readcmdfile failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {   /* output lines read from file */
        printf ("path[%lu]: %s\n", i + 1, paths[i]);
        free (paths[i]);        /* free memory holding line */
    }
    free (paths);   /* free pointers */

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** if you allocate memory -- it is up to you to preserve a pointer to the beginning of each block -- so it can be freed when it is no longer needed)

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat paths.txt
/home/bla/dirname
/home/bla/bla/file1.txt
/home/bla/bla/file2.txt
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/readpaths <paths.txt
path[1]: /home/bla/dirname
path[2]: /home/bla/bla/file1.txt
path[3]: /home/bla/bla/file2.txt
```

As you can see the function has simply read each line of the input file, allocated 3 pointers, allocated for each line and assigned the address for each block to the corresponding pointer and then returns a pointer to the collection to `main()` where it is assigned to `paths` there. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I will create a method for if/else blocks. I feel like they're redundant.

```
 switch(updateParam) {
     case UPDATE1:
            method(); /*do if/else here*/
            break;
     ...............
     ...............
 }
```

However, you can still put them there if you do not need the method for other times and you concern about performance issues as function call costs more than just collective instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking into [regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/). That way you read everything, then match with regular expressions and handle your matches.

Regular expressions exist for this purpose: to make parsing elegant.

Answer (score 0):

In your program, you are passing `3` array of `char` to store the `3` lines read from the file. But this is very inefficient as the input file may contain more lines and in future, you may have the requirement to read more than `3` lines from the file. Instead, you can pass the array of `char` pointers and allocate memory to them and copy the content of lines read from the file. As pointed by Jonathan (in comment), if you use standard I/O then you can use function like `fgets()` to read lines
from input file.
Read a line from the file and allocate memory to the pointer and copy the line, read from the file to it. If the line is too long, you can read remaining part in consecutive calls to `fgets()` and use `realloc` to expand the existing memory, the pointer is pointing to, large enough to accommodate the remaining part of the line read.

Putting these all together, you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF_SZ    100
#define MAX_LINES 3  /* Maximum number of lines to be read from file */

int readCMDFile(const char* cmdFile, char *paths[MAX_LINES]) {
    int count, next_line, line_cnt, new_line_found;
    char tmpbuf[BUF_SZ];
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen(cmdFile, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror ("Failed to open file");
        return -1;
    }

    next_line = 1; /* Keep track of next line */
    count = 1;     /* Used to calculate the size of memory, if need to reallocte 
                    * in case when a line in the file is too long to read in one go */
    line_cnt = 0;  /* Keep track of index of array of char pointer */
    new_line_found = 0; 

    while ((line_cnt < MAX_LINES) && (fgets (tmpbuf, BUF_SZ, fp) != NULL)) {
        if (tmpbuf[strlen(tmpbuf) - 1] == '\n') {
            tmpbuf[strlen(tmpbuf) - 1] = '\0';
            new_line_found = 1;
        } else {
            new_line_found = 0;
        }

        if (next_line) {
            paths[line_cnt] = calloc (sizeof (tmpbuf), sizeof (char));
            if (paths[line_cnt] == NULL) {
                perror ("Failed to allocate memory");
                return -1;
            }
            next_line = 0;
            count = 1;
        } else {
            char *ptr = realloc (paths[line_cnt], sizeof (tmpbuf) * (++count));
            if (ptr == NULL) {
                free (paths[line_cnt]);
                perror ("Failed to reallocate memory");
                return -1;
            } else {
                paths[line_cnt] = ptr;
            }
        }

        /* Using strcat to copy the buffer to allocated memory because
         * calloc initialize the block of memory with zero, so it will
         * be same as strcpy when first time copying the content of buffer 
         * to the allocated memory and fgets add terminating null-character 
         * to the buffer so, it will concatenate the content of buffer to 
         * allocated memory in case when the pointer is reallocated */
        strcat (paths[line_cnt], tmpbuf);
        if (new_line_found) {
            line_cnt++;
            next_line = 1;
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return line_cnt;
}

int main(void) {
    int lines_read, index;
    const char *file_name = "cmdfile.txt";
    char *paths[MAX_LINES] = {NULL};

    lines_read = readCMDFile(file_name, paths);
    if (lines_read < 0) {
        printf ("Failed to read file %s\n", file_name);
    }

    /* Check the output */
    for (index = 0; index < lines_read; index++) {
        printf ("Line %d: %s\n", index, paths[index]);
    }

    /* Free the allocated memory */
    for (index = 0; index < lines_read; index++) {
        free (paths[index]);
        paths[index] = NULL;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ cat cmdfile.txt
/home/bla/dirname
/home/bla/bla/file1.txt
/home/bla/bla/file2.txt

$ ./a.out
Line 0: /home/bla/dirname
Line 1: /home/bla/bla/file1.txt
Line 2: /home/bla/bla/file2.txt
```

Note that the above program is not taking care of empty lines in the file as it has not been mentioned in the question. But if you want, you can add that check just after removing the trailing newline character from the line read from the file.